# InvalidRegistration in FCM pushnotification

Tags: c#, asp.net, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am Trying to use FCM for push Notification But I get a Error

> {"multicast_id":5438269995043250343,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}

My Code is:

```
var applicationID = "AAAAU1NcEvw:APA91bF6V....blq3lFdU";
            var senderId = "357...668";
            string deviceId = "cmWVx1UBniA:APA91b.....ukG77K";
            WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
            tRequest.Method = "post";
            tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            var data = new
            {
                to = deviceId,
                notification = new
                {
                    body = "This is the message",
                    title = "This is the title",
                    icon = "myicon"
                }
            };
            var json = jss.Serialize(data);
            Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", senderId));
            tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                    {
                        String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                        // Response.Write(sResponseFromServer);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Share solution, if you have solve this issue. Facing same issue .

Comment: InvalidRegistration issue persists for years and bothers developers globally as it seems. Time that Firebase team wakes up and adds more detailed error. Obviously the error text does not always reflect the real cause.

Answer (score 1):

As the error States this means that the `deviceId` is not registered you have probably misspelled it or it was refreshed.

Also if you somehow encounter this when sending to a topic make sure you have prefixed `"/topics/"` so the good people at firebase know you are sending to a topic and not a specific dude.